# Merge datasets based on closest lowest date

Tags: r, date, merge

```
Machines = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B')
Week = c('201651',  '201635', '201714', '201516', '201438', '201704', '201651')
Manual.Code = c('M123', 'M467', 'M123', 'M846', 'M898', 'QQQQ' ,'M898')
DF1 = data.frame(Machines, Week, Manual)

Manual.Code = c('M123', 'M123', 'M123', 'CTTY', 'M467', 'M.99', 'M846', 'M898') 
Version = as.numeric(c('2.0', '1.1', '1.0', '2.0', '1.6', '1.67', '3.2', '2.4'))
Release_week = (c('201711', '201638', '201612', '201424', '201552', '201345', 
'201719', '201647'))
DF2 = data_frame(Manual.Code, Version, Release_week)
```

I have been using R for some months now, but I still consider myself a beginner. My next problem involves the usage of a manual for maintenance on machine types at a certain point in time. DF1 are my machines and DF2 are the versions of the manual used.

```
DF1:

Type  Week    Manual.Code
A     201651  M123
A     201635  M467
B     201714  M123
C     201516  M846
D     201438  M898
A     201704  QQQQ
B     201651  M898

DF2: 

Manual.Code Version Release_week
M123        2.0     201711
M123        1.1     201638
M123        1.0     201612
CTTY        2.0     201424
M467        1.6     201552
M.99        1.67    201345
M846        3.2     201719 
M898        2.4     201647

Desired output DF3: 
Type  Week    Manual.Code  Used.Version
A     201651  M123         1.1 
A     201635  M467         1.6
B     201714  M123         2.0
C     201516  M846         NA
D     201438  M898         NA
A     201704  QQQQ         NA
B     201651  M898         2.4
```

I have had a look at other threads and from that I think that the solution is in either rolling joins, data.tables using unequal-joins, or a fuzzyjoin from the fuzzyjoin package, but I haven't managed to get either one of these solutions to work yet. What would be the best way to merge these two datasets?

p.s. sizes real datasets:

```
DF1: 35000 x 43
DF2: 217000 x 14
```

Comment: Can you please post a code for the data, which we can copy directly into R.

Comment: I'll create a code :)

Comment: 5th row in your expected output `D     201438  M898         NA`, why is it `NA`? Why not `2.4`?

Comment: A solution might be to use a LEFT_JOIN to get all matches and then filter for the closest release week less than the week

Comment: @zx8754 Because that version of the manual was introduced after the version of that manual and I have no information on which version existed prior to the release of it.

Comment: @zx8754 I think they need NA there because the `Week` has to be after `Release_week` in order for that version to have been used. You can add that as an extra filter in your answer.

Comment: @AntoniosK good point, how do you explain row2: `A     201635  M467         1.6` where release date is `201652` ?

Comment: I can't explain it :-D

Comment: @Joey can you explain? Your expected output is not consistent, why 5th row is NA, and 2nd row is not?

Comment: @zx8754 Sorry! My mistake when creating the dummy data. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table` package allows for *rolling joins*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF2)[setDT(DF1), on = .(Manual.Code, Release_week = Week), roll = +Inf]
```

> ```
>    Manual.Code Version Release_week Machines
> 1:        M123     1.1       201651        A
> 2:        M467     1.6       201635        A
> 3:        M123     2.0       201714        B
> 4:        M846      NA       201516        C
> 5:        M898      NA       201438        D
> 6:        QQQQ      NA       201704        A
> 7:        M898     2.4       201651        B
> ```

Please note that only integer, double or character colums may be roll joined. So, make sure to use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` parameter when calling `data.frame()`.

The result can be fine-tuned to comply with OP's expected result:

```
library(data.table)
result <- setDT(DF2)[setDT(DF1), on = .(Manual.Code, Release_week = Week), roll = +Inf]
setnames(result, c("Release_week", "Version"), c("Week", "Used.Version"))
setcolorder(result, names(DF1))
result
```

> ```
>    Machines   Week Manual.Code Used.Version
> 1:        A 201651        M123          1.1
> 2:        A 201635        M467          1.6
> 3:        B 201714        M123          2.0
> 4:        C 201516        M846           NA
> 5:        D 201438        M898           NA
> 6:        A 201704        QQQQ           NA
> 7:        B 201651        M898          2.4
> ```

#### Data

Note that the data as provided by the OP are used but with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
Machines = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B')
Week = c('201651',  '201635', '201714', '201516', '201438', '201704', '201651')
Manual.Code = c('M123', 'M467', 'M123', 'M846', 'M898', 'QQQQ' ,'M898')
DF1 = data.frame(Machines, Week, Manual.Code, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Manual.Code = c('M123', 'M123', 'M123', 'CTTY', 'M467', 'M.99', 'M846', 'M898') 
Version = as.numeric(c('2.0', '1.1', '1.0', '2.0', '1.6', '1.67', '3.2', '2.4'))
Release_week = (c('201711', '201638', '201612', '201424', '201552', '201345', 
'201719', '201647'))
DF2 = data.frame(Manual.Code, Version, Release_week, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This approach delivers me way cleaner results. I think that the dummy data was too simplistic and therefor the left_join results perform well on that data, but not so much on the real data.

Comment: Indeed, rolling joins are quite handy for many similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

Using *dplyr*, *left_join*, then *arrange* them by absolute (*abs*) difference between weeks, and get the first one (*slice*), finally assign Version to NA where *Release_week* is later than *Week*:

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(DF2, by = "Manual.Code") %>% 
  #if you have different column names use this:
  #left_join(DF2, by = c("Manual" = "Manual.Code")) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  arrange(rn, abs(Release_week - Week)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-rn) %>% 
  mutate(Version = ifelse(Release_week > Week, NA, Version))

# # A tibble: 7 x 5
#   Type    Week Manual.Code Version Release_week
#   <chr>  <int> <chr>         <dbl>        <int>
# 1 A     201651 M123            1.1       201638
# 2 A     201635 M467            1.6       201552
# 3 B     201714 M123            2         201711
# 4 C     201516 M846           NA         201719
# 5 D     201438 M898           NA         201647
# 6 A     201704 QQQQ           NA             NA
# 7 B     201651 M898            2.4       201647
```

---

Example input data:

```
DF1 <- read.table(text = "
Type  Week    Manual.Code
A     201651  M123
A     201635  M467
B     201714  M123
C     201516  M846
D     201438  M898
A     201704  QQQQ
B     201651  M898
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF2 <- read.table(text = "
Manual.Code Version Release_week
M123        2.0     201711
M123        1.1     201638
M123        1.0     201612
CTTY        2.0     201424
M467        1.6     201552
M.99        1.67    201345
M846        3.2     201719 
M898        2.4     201647
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Great idea, but when I try it myself this error pops up: Error: `by` can't contain join column `Manual.Code` which is missing from LHS

Comment: @Joey maybe in your real data you have different column names `Manual.Code` vs `Manual` ?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my own dummy data that I overlooked. Do you know too how to include that extra filter @Antoniosk was talking about?

Comment: @zx8754 He wrote below that he only wants manuals from preceding weeks, you also take those after.

Comment: @Joey see edit, now it should give you expected output. Note that my week numbers are "numeric" not "character/factor".

Comment: @Joey If you only want preceding weeks you will get a lot of NAs. If you leave his last line away or in my answer the `& df2$release_week <= week` then you also get release weeks after the week.

Comment: Thanks  to all for all the help. I got confused myself because I constructed a faulty dataset, but the final solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to your problem. However I get a different output then you when just taking the preceding weeks. What I do is to look up the closest preceding week with a function and then make a LEFT JOIN with that column together with the manual.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 = data.frame(type = c("A","A","B","C","D","A","B"),
             week = c(201651, 201635, 201714, 201516, 201438, 201704, 201651),
             manual.code = c("M123", "M467", "M123", "M846", "M898", "QQQQ", "M898"))

df2 = data.frame(manual.code = c("M123","M123","M123","CTTY","M467","M.99","M846", "M898"),
             version = c("2.0","1.1","1.0", "2.0", "1.6", "1.67", "3.2", "2.4"),
             release_week = c(201711,201638,201612,201424,201652,201345,201719,201647))


df3 = df1
df3$closest_week = NA

get_clostest_week = function(manual, week){
  manual_weeks = df2[which(df2$manual.code == manual & df2$release_week <= week),"release_week"]
  if(length(manual_weeks)==0){
    return(NA)
  }
  diff = abs(manual_weeks - week)
  manual_weeks[which(diff == min(diff))]
}

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df3))){
  df3$closest_week[i] = get_clostest_week(df3$manual.code[i], df3$week[i])
}



df3 = merge(df3, df2, by.x = c("manual.code","closest_week"), 
        by.y = c("manual.code","release_week"), all.x = TRUE)))
```

(The answer has been edited because of misunderstanding of the problem.)

Comment: Question is not about exact matching.

Comment: Does he need a LEFT JOIN or what do you mean with "not about exact matching"?

Comment: I have tried this and it gives me only 100% matches between the two datasets. However, for the cases where I do not have a full match I would like to have the results based on the closest preceding week.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you exactly want. I try to find out if there is an easy solution to that problem.